# HTMLPurifier vs Kses

Tags: php, html, filter, htmlpurifier

What are the advantages / disadvantages of both?

Which of them would you use to filter comment that user a posting on a website?

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison lists the differences probably the most objective and comprehensively. It seems to advise htmLawed (a fork) over kses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

kses has not been updated in 7 years now -- I think that's enough to take it out of the picture immediately.

However, the real question is: *Do you **need** to accept HTML input in user comments?*

Because if you do not, the correct solution to the problem is using `htmlspecialchars` before you echo the comments as HTML, and that's it. Nothing more is required.

Even if you need to allow users to format their comments, there are various alternative markup languages (BBCode, MarkDown, Textile -- this is what SO uses when you type) which are both widely used and more than adequate for the task.

Consider that *you can even build Wikipedia without accepting HTML input*.

Comment: @IainCollins: Of course you can craft XSS if you use a powerful enough flavor of MarkDown et al. My point is that *you should not be doing that*. And even if you do, `htmlspecialchars` will prevent XSS.

Comment: That comment was intended intended to be a reply to another post related to escaping when using markdown (comment removed); I'd left it open to come back to later and got the tabs mixed up. I note that while advocating "you should not be doing that" that it's used in your reply and in the post, which may give pause for thought. Note if you do use markdown or similar then using PHP's htmlspecialchars() isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

A good article that advised me was:

[HTML Sanitisation: The Devil’s In The Details (And The Vulnerabilities)](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2010/08/html-sanitisation-the-devils-in-the-details-and-the-vulnerabilities/)

I use HTMLPurifier in almost all my projects because with caching, there is not a big performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a port of Drupal XSS filter. It's advanced version of Kses.
https://github.com/ymakux/xss

```
$filter = new Filter();

// List of allowed protocols
$allowed_protocols = array('http', 'ftp', 'mailto');

// List of allowed tags you want to keep in text  
$allowed_tags = array('a', 'i', 'b', 'em', 'span', 'strong', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'table', 'tr', 'td', 'thead', 'th', 'tbody');

$filter->addAllowedProtocols($allowed_protocols);
$filter->addAllowedTags($allowed_tags);

// Parse string
$filtered_string = $filter->xss($string);
```